# jQuery Scrolling to the next text occurence

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a search function in my web-page that searches for text. If the text is found, it is highlighted and if not, a pop-up saying that nothing has been found will pop up.

I want to make 2 other features in this search functionality. I have created 2 new buttons, a 'Next' button and a 'Previous' button. Right now, They only work when highlighting the occurrences but I would like it to scroll down to the next or to the previous text occurrence that it has found.(just like when pressing f3 on the keyboard)  How can I go about doing this?

The following is my code :

```
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<pre>
<div class="SearchButtonsSection">

          <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="txtSearch">
          <button><a href="#" class="search btn">Search</a></button>
          <button><a href="#" class="next btn">Next</a></button>
          <button><a href="#" class="previous btn">Previous</a></button>
    </div>

        <div id="content" style="with:100%">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in felis ut dui dictum cursus. In at congue dui. Fusce sit amet ligula faucibus, tincidunt ligula nec, elementum dolor. Integer dignissim tellus vitae ligula egestas, laoreet dictum mauris laoreet. Nulla lorem turpis, hendrerit quis urna ut, bibendum hendrerit elit. Sed non lorem tincidunt, viverra purus fringilla, dignissim mauris. Phasellus ac pellentesque enim. Fusce et mattis nibh. Maecenas non imperdiet nisi, lobortis consequat mauris. Etiam suscipit odio vitae interdum cursus. Aliquam ut rhoncus metus. Donec sed malesuada augue, eu interdum orci. Vestibulum porta lobortis orci a maximus. Etiam id tellus eleifend, condimentum nisi ac, lobortis ante. Nullam nec libero porttitor, dictum lacus sit amet, faucibus nulla.

Maecenas scelerisque posuere sem sed auctor. Ut eget dapibus diam, molestie eleifend est. In interdum lacus vitae ullamcorper convallis. Sed nec felis vitae lacus rhoncus suscipit commodo eget diam. Phasellus tincidunt, turpis vel ultricies cursus, massa est egestas mi, ut faucibus velit neque nec dui. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus rhoncus, felis a sagittis condimentum, quam purus mattis urna, id ullamcorper dui mauris id nisl. Donec bibendum a nunc at hendrerit. In porttitor turpis at lorem tincidunt venenatis. Mauris mattis dolor sed libero iaculis, quis mattis dui ornare. Nullam euismod, metus vel blandit viverra, ipsum elit fermentum felis, eu facilisis nisi mi non nisl. Integer enim erat, feugiat eget consectetur non, dapibus id nisi </p></div>



<style>

 .highlighted {
     background-color:yellow;
 }
 .highlight {
     background-color: #fff34d;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     /* FF1+ */
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     /* Saf3-4 */
     border-radius: 5px;
     /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Saf5, Chrome */
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
     /* FF3.5+ */
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
     /* Saf3.0+, Chrome */
     box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
     /* Opera 10.5+, IE 9.0 */
 }
 .highlight {
     padding:1px 4px;
     margin:0 -4px;
 }

    .searchBtns{
        height:20px;
        width:100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        float:left;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .SearchButtonSection{
        height:300px;
        width:100%;

    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:black;
    }

    .button{
        float:right;
        margin-left:50px;
    }
</style>


<script>
function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm, selector) {
    if (searchTerm) {
        //var wholeWordOnly = new RegExp("\\g"+searchTerm+"\\g","ig"); //matches whole word only
        //var anyCharacter = new RegExp("\\g["+searchTerm+"]\\g","ig"); //matches any word with any of search chars characters
        var selector = selector || "#content"; //use body as selector if none provided
        var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
        var matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
        if (matches != null && matches.length > 0) {
            $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted'); //Remove old search highlights  

            //Remove the previous matches
            $span = $('#content span');
            $span.replaceWith($span.html());

    if (searchTerm === "&") {
        searchTerm = "&amp;";
        searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
    }
            $(selector).html($(selector).html().replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='match'>" + searchTerm + "</span>"));
            $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');

            var i = 0;

            $('.next').off('click').on('click', function () {
                i++;

                if (i >= $('.match').length) i = 0;

                $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');
                $('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.match').eq(i).offset().top
                }, 300);
            });
            $('.previous').off('click').on('click', function () {

                i--;

                if (i < 0) i = $('.match').length - 1;

                $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');
                $('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.match').eq(i).offset().top
                }, 300);
            });




            if ($('.highlighted:first').length) { //if match found, scroll to where the first one appears
                $(window).scrollTop($('.highlighted:first').position().top);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).on('click', '.search', function (event) {

    $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted").removeClass("match");
    if (!searchAndHighlight($('.txtSearch').val())) {
        alert("No results found");
    }


});
</script>


<script>
function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm, selector) {
    if (searchTerm) {
        //var wholeWordOnly = new RegExp("\\g"+searchTerm+"\\g","ig"); //matches whole word only
        //var anyCharacter = new RegExp("\\g["+searchTerm+"]\\g","ig"); //matches any word with any of search chars characters
        var selector = selector || "#content"; //use body as selector if none provided
        var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
        var matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
        if (matches != null && matches.length > 0) {
            $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted'); //Remove old search highlights  

            //Remove the previous matches
            $span = $('#content span');
            $span.replaceWith($span.html());

    if (searchTerm === "&") {
        searchTerm = "&";
        searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
    }
            $(selector).html($(selector).html().replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='match'>" + searchTerm + "</span>"));
            $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');

            var i = 0;

            $('.next').off('click').on('click', function () {
                i++;

                if (i >= $('.match').length) i = 0;

                $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');
                $('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.match').eq(i).offset().top
                }, 300);
            });
            $('.previous').off('click').on('click', function () {

                i--;

                if (i < 0) i = $('.match').length - 1;

                $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');
                $('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.match').eq(i).offset().top
                }, 300);
            });




            if ($('.highlighted:first').length) { //if match found, scroll to where the first one appears
                $(window).scrollTop($('.highlighted:first').position().top);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).on('click', '.search', function (event) {

    $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted").removeClass("match");
    if (!searchAndHighlight($('.txtSearch').val())) {
        alert("No results found");
    }


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by replacing:

```
$('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({scrollTop: $('.match').eq(i).offset().top}, 300);
```

with:

```
$(window).scrollTop($('.match').eq(i).offset().top);
```

I did not test whether it worked with animate as for some reason jsfiddle was not recognizing the function however It appears your issue is that you are trying to scroll an element without `overflow: auto` so it expands making the window scrollable instead. So either scroll the window or set `overflow: auto;` in your container.

Comment: The code that I have inserted was already functioning but I wanted to add the feature of when clicking on next / previous the window would scroll to the next/previous occurrence. I have tried the overflow:auto; but it still doesn't work

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In your code you have the explicit behavior of scrolling to the match when clicking on next or previous so when replacing the element that we want to scroll It works as you intend it. If i click on next It will scroll to the next occurrence (if the next occurrence is outside of the view-port and requires scrolling to it) and the same happens when I click on previous. So I'm not sure what is not working for you.

Comment: can there be any particular reason that this code works on jsFiddle and not on Brackets? on jsFiddle works perfectly fine, but on brackets it just doesn't scroll although everything else works fine

Comment: @Burdy I don't think so. However can you check the JS logs and see if you get any errors when pressing on next or previous buttons?

Comment: There are no errors whatsoever, in none of the buttons. I think the issue is that the only jsFiddle jQuery plugin is the JQuery 1.9.1 ( JQuery 1.3.0b1) but I cannot use this since I have other features in the website and none of it will work with v.1.9.1

Comment: In jsFiddle you can change version of jQuery so try changing it to see if it is in fact a jQuery version issue, but I doubt it.

Comment: I think it is, because every time I use the 3.3.1 it does not work

Comment: Great. Now all you have to do is debug :P until you find the source of the issue :D Also looking at your code I don't see a reason for which you absolutely need to use jQuery for this so if you really can't find the source just move it to vanilla.